# How do I change the Windows 10 system language?

Tags: windows-10, language

The operating system language -- menus, control panel, calendar -- somehow changed to Hebrew. How do I change back to English. Note that the "Set default language" button for English is disabled (screenshot below), suggesting that it already is the system language -- yet menus remain in Hebrew.

[image]

Comment: use the desktop control panel->region&language entry and try to change it there

Answer (score 1):

The key word here is "override" (which I translated from Hebrew in the image above as "bypass.") [image]

Press WINDOWS-I. Choose Time and Language -> Additional date, time & regional settings -> Add a language -> Advanced settings -> "Override for Windows display language."